# Using a truthy/falsy check in Typescript vs explicit check against null or undefined

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```js
class Foo {
    // some implementation of Foo here
}

interface Bar {
    foo?: Foo;  // type of Bar.foo is Foo | undefined
}
```

Suppose you want to guard against undefined for `Bar.foo`.

```js
function func() {
   if (myBar.foo === undefined) {
      return;
   }

   // ok to use myBar.foo (assuming no ill-advised use of any)
}
```

Is there any point to the explicit `=== undefined` check above.  Is it not functionally equivalent to `if (!myBar.foo) return;` ?

I understand that null and undefined are different.  I understand that the `!myBar.foo` is a broader check in normal Javascript.  But in TS-land, doesn't TS already prevent `myBar.foo` from taking on any "falsy" value other than undefined?

So should it not be safe to always use the shorter `!myBar.foo` style check and save 11 characters?

The only exception I can think of is if you allow developers in your codebase to casually use `any`. Then, someone might, in another part of the code do something ill-advised, such as:

```
myBar.foo = 4567 as any;
```

In this case, your check would determine it's "ok" to access and use foo, and it would be wrong.  But I'd argue that's a result of poor use of `any`.  And in fact, the shorter check seems to be stronger in the negative case:

```js
myBar.foo = false as any;
```

In this case, false will be "falsy", and it'll actually be caught and your function won't try to use the `foo`.

Is there anything else I may be missing?  Any strong reason to prefer `=== undefined` here?

Answer (score 1):

It depends...

---

> Is there any point to the `explicit === undefined` check above? Is it not functionally equivalent to `if (!myBar.foo) return;`?

In this case, yes, you are correct. A check like that will narrow the type with all falsy values, leaving only `Foo`.

But this is not always advisable, in all cases.

---

> So should it not be safe to always use the shorter `!myBar.foo` style check and save 11 characters?

It depends on whether all falsy values should be filtered out. `0` and `""` are two values that will be falsy in javascript, so `string` and `number` maybe not do the right thing.

```
declare const foo: number | string | undefined
if (foo) {
    foo // number | string
} else {
    foo // number | string | undefined
}
```

Here typescript knows that `foo` could be `"" | 0` in the else path and therefore you don't get a narrowed type at all.

However, this works, because `""` and `0` are both `!== undefined`

```
declare const foo: number | string | undefined
if (foo !== undefined) {
    foo // number | string
} else {
    foo // undefined
}
```

---

> The only exception I can think of is if you allow developers in your codebase to casually use `any`.

Guarding against this is not your concern. If people cast things to `any` then they are disregarding best practices and the trouble they get into is of their own making.

Assuming that your code is expected to be used in Typescript codebases, just make your logic as correct as possible for how your types are declared, and expect Typescript to enforce all that for you.

---

You have to be aware of what values are falsy, and use the right conditions to filter them out. `!foo` is great, when it's right, and when it's not right then use `foo != null`*  or `foo !== undefined`.

---

* comparisons with `null` is the *one* time I believe the `==` or `!=` operators are allowed. This is because they compare against `null` and `undefined` both, which can be a really handy shortcut.

Comment: You say "It depends on whether all falsy values should be filtered out."  I was asking specifically about the example code (which I thought was clear in my question), where the possible type is `Foo | undefined`.  You expanded the example to use `number | string | undefined`.  I'm asking very specifically about `Foo|undefined`, in which case, I don't think it depends, does it?  Simply *because* no other falsy value (besides undefined) is even possible (due to TS type checking). Right?

Comment: "You have to be aware of what values are falsy, and use the right conditions to filter them out. !foo is great, when it's right, and when it's not right then use foo != null* or foo !== undefined"

Yes, precisely this. And my question was: with the given code, is there any advantage to `=== undefined` over the shorter check. I cannot see one in this case, but that's why I wanted to double check this specific scenario (apologies if it seemed like I was asking about truthy/falsy more broadly -- I wasn't).

Comment: Your example code is one of the cases where `!foo` is fine, because `undefined` is the only possible falsy value. Which was the "You are correct." near the start of my answer. But I didn't want you or future readers of this question to think that was exactly the same as `foo !== undefined` in all cases because it's not.

Comment: Yes thank you. I was well aware it’s not exactly the same in all cases, but it’s good to be clear for all future readers. Thanks!